# unique between 2 columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i need to create a validation to my table "candidate_knowledges", basically in this table it accepts to columns (candidate_id, software_id), i cannot let create user_id and software more then one. but i think my validation is wrong or im not doing it right.
What im trying to say in validation is that can only exist one software_id and one candidate_id on the table, this way the candidate dont have duplicate entries.

```
Ex:  'software_id'         => 'required|integer|unique:candidate_knowledges,candidate_id,'.$candidate->id,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to allow only one software for each candidate:

```
$rules = [
    'software_id' =>
        'required',
        'integer',
        'min:1',
         Rule::unique('candidate_knowledges')->where('candidate_id', $candidate->id),
    ],
];
```

In general I would suggest using fluent validation syntax (it's match easier to use and update), but if you can't (laravel < 5.3 or any other reasons):

```
'software_id' => 'required|integer|unique:candidate_knowledges,NULL,NULL,candidate_id,' . $candidate->id,
```

Hope it helps.